# Why is the String color's name that is outputted to the user does not match the color name that is in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, search

I am trying to write a recursive algorithm that allows a user to choose a color based on a number the user enters into the program. The colors' names are stored in a String[] array. I cannot figure out why the color that is outputted to the user does not match the color from the array with the index that matches the number the user entered. Here is my code:

```
/*
The class allows the user to search through a list a colors to pick a new
favorite color
*/
class PickAColor
{
    //Global Variables
   public int maxSize;
    public int numOfColors;
    static public String[] colors;

    //Scanner
    static Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Constructor
    public PickAColor()
    {

    }

    public PickAColor(int maxSize)
    {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.numOfColors = 0;
        colors = new String[maxSize];
        populateColors();
    }

    //Functions
    //Function to populate colors
    public void populateColors()
    {
        //Add colors to array
        push(0, "red");
        push(1, "orange");
        push(2, "yellow");
        push(3, "green");
        push(4, "blue");
        push(5, "purple");
        push(6, "violet");
        push(7, "teal");
        push(8, "magenta");
        push(9, "brown");
        push(10, "black");
        push(11, "white");
        push(12, "periwinkle");
    }

    //Function to push new color
    public String push(int cntr, String color)
    {
       colors[cntr] = color;

       return colors[cntr];
    }

    //Function to see if stack is empty
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return numOfColors == 0;
    }

    //Function to see if stack is full
    public boolean isFull()
    {
        return numOfColors == maxSize;
    }

    //Function to loop through array
    public static String Search(int num)
    {
        //Variables
        int cntr = 0;
        String color = null;

        //While loop iterates through array based on user's input
        while(num > cntr)
        {
            color = colors[cntr];
            cntr++;
            num--;
            Search(num);
        }
        return color;
    }

    //Function to randomly organize an array
    //Function to ask user for favorite color
    public static void askUser()
    {
        //Variables
        int response;
        String color;

        //Message user
        System.out.println("Do you like your favorite color?"
                + " \nIs it still your favorite color today?"
                + " \nHow about you spin the wheel of colors to randomly"
                + " pick a new favorite color?"
                + " \nEnter a number. ");

        response = Integer.parseInt(myScan.nextLine());

        System.out.println("...\nGood luck! ");

        color = Search(response);

       //Message
        System.out.println("Your new favorite color is: " + color);
    }

    //Function to ask if user wants to repeat this
    public static void repeat()
    {
        //Variables
        String response;
        String color;

        int slots;

        System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (y/n) ");

        response = ScottN_RecursionExcerise.myScanner.nextLine();

        switch(response)
        {
            case "y":
            {
                System.out.println("Enter a number. ");

                slots = Integer.parseInt(myScan.nextLine());

                color = Search(slots);

                System.out.println("Your new favorite color is: " + color);

                System.out.println();
                repeat();

            }
            case "n":
            {
                System.out.println();
                menu();
            }
            default:
            {
                ScottN_RecursionExcerise.menuRedirect();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I create a new instance of this class and begin the algorithm in my menu in the main class.

```
//Create a new color instance
                PickAColor pc = new PickAColor(13);

                //Get user's resposne
                pc.askUser();

                System.out.println();

                pc.repeat();

                menu();
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A lot can be said about this code, but your specific question's answer is that the Search method should look like this:

```
public static String Search(int num)
{
    // Basic validation of 'num' omitted...
    return colors[num];
}
```

You don't need to loop the array, since you know that the color you look for is at index num in the array. Just go get it :)